# HTML <video> onended event not firing in Firefox 29

Tags: html, video

I'm having trouble getting the 'onended' event working in Firefox 29 for a HTML video element.

Here's some example code:

```
<video id="video"></video>

<script>
var video = document.getElementById("video");
video.onended = function() { alert('Ended'); }
video.play();
</script>
```

I left source files and such out of here so I do understand that the above example will never start playing but in my real code it does work.

Anyways. Firefox is not doing anything. It does fire onerror and oncanplay so I know I'm correctly binding the events...

Help?

Comment: Take the `#` out of the video ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Firefox doesn't like the 'video.onended = ...' syntax. It works for 'video.canplay = ...' but for onended it only works like this:

```
video.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    alert('Ended');
},false);
```

Not very consistent but a valuable life lesson: The web is not consistent. Ever.

Answer (score 1):

```
<video id="video"></video>
```

Your id "#video" does not match with getElementById("video")

Comment: Thnx but that was a typo in the pseudo code i posted here. The actual code works except for the onended event in FF (onerror, oncanplay do work)